# How to solve fixing div at certain position by using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am facing problem in fixing a div at certain position, I have to fix the div at certain position at right side, the middle part must be scrollable, but after logged in when I go to profile page, at first time the div is not fixed but when I refreshed the profile page it is fixed.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function profileInfo() {
        var element = $('.follow-scroll');
        var originalY = element.offset().top;
        var topMargin = 0;
        element.css('position', 'relative');
        $(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            element.stop(false, false).animate(
            {
                top: scrollTop < originalY ? 0 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
            }, 0);
        });
    }
})
```

Html code:

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2 ord-3 npd visible-lg">
            <div class="pfasdfxd follow-scroll">
                <div class="prfsdbg">
                    <div class="prfasdr text-center">
                        <img src="/images/Latte-image.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="ntfsnt">Don't be basic</div>
                    <p class="prsntxt">
                        Upgrade to premium today!<br>
                        Starting at just $15
                    </p>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a href="#" type="button" class="ntfbtn btsm">View plans</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So you want to call profileInfo() when you route to profile page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are required to using jQuery I should do this to fix the div at a certain location (in this case fixed to the right side and Y in top is the number of pixels you want from top)

```
function profileInfo() {
    $('.follow-scroll').css({position: 'fixed', right: 0, top: "Ypx"});
}
```

If you always should have it fixed to a certain location I should have done this in CSS instead.

```
.follow-scroll {position:fixed, right:0; top: Ypx;}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help.it worked for me.but at the first time when I opened profile page the position is not fixed after refreshing the position is fixed..Can you please help how to fix the position when profile page is loaded..

Comment: Where do you call the profileInfo function? Seems to me that When you call the function it is sometimes not initiated yet. Put the call inside of document ready?